# pdflatex of list of files

Tags: compiling

I have a Directory in which there are 25 directories and each directory contains .tex file.

I need to apply pdflatex command to create pdf files. I try this command but it does not work. I get an error. Any suggestion ?

```
find . -name "*.tex"|pdflatex
```

Comment: `find . -name \*.tex -exec pdflatex \{\} \;` would be the syntax you are looking for but better really to cd to each directory and run tex just with the local filename so aux and pdf get written to right place

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, It does not work

Comment: It works if you do it right (and you haven't got spaces in your file name) what operating system and shell are you using?

Comment: I am on mac os x and I am using /bin/bash

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name \*.tex -exec pdflatex \{\} \;
```

is the `find` syntax you were looking for but it is better to run pdflatex
in each directory so pdf and aux files get written to the correct place, so assuming bash shell, perhaps

```
 for i in */*.tex; do (cd ${i%/*}; pdflatex ${i##*/};) done
```

Comment: ! I can't find file `*.tex'.
<*> *.tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, How can avoid if there is an error in some files or there is no .tex in a subdirectory?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: Sorry, It works and it creates the .pdf files in the current directory but files have the same name so finally I get just the last one. How can i force the command to create each.pdf in the corresponding subdirectory.

Comment: I always have the same error with the loop cds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22039/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-phdstudent).

Answer (score 3):

A batch solution

```
@echo off

set path=D:/mtTeX/miktex/bin;%path%

for /D %%a in (*) do (
cd %%a
for %%b in (*.tex) do  pdflatex %%b
cd .. )
```

Comment: I am on mac os x